# Build Tree/Parent-Child like structure with data from a sql table with two columns

Tags: c#, sql

I have sql table with two columns Parent, Child with no primary key. The data is  huge.
Now, I am required to develop a hierarchy of Parent->Child->children of child.

Eg: Data in the table looks something like below:

```
Parent Child
  1      2
  1      3
  1      10
  1      11
  2      5
  2      10
  2      7
  3      1
  3      13
  4      15
  7      17
  8      20
```

Now, I need Parent->Children->All children of All children and so on under one group: Group1 - 1,2,3,10,11,5,7,13; Group2-4,15; Group3 - 7,17; Group4 - 8,20. Could someone guide me the best/efficient way of achieving this using sql or c#?

Thanks!

Comment: What RDMBS are you using?
If Oracle - you need to research START WITH Connect By.
If SQL Server - start reading up on Common Table Expressions.

Comment: do you want to concatenate children in strings on server side or do you want to get it in C# lists at your client?

Comment: There must be a ton dups of this question here...

Comment: Thanks Declan_K. I am using C# for programming and SQL to store data.

Comment: @Icarus - This clearly is not the answer! A link to resources would help. Thanks for your time

Comment: @RomanPekar - A C# list would be nice. I need to generate a text file with the results, so the approach doesn't really matter I guess, am not sure. Please suggest. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Shame it wasn't implemented as a nested set (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) because although you still have to do some SQL leg work, it becomes *far* easier.

Comment: @Moo-Juice - Thank you so much for the response. I was unable to follow or adopt the methodology you mentioned. Please guide me how I can use it with the structure i currently have.

Comment: @user2643324, is it a mistake or intentional that children can appear in more than one parent?  (10 appears in both 1 & 2)

Comment: @Moo-Juice - It is a possible scenario that one child can be a child of more than one parent. Thank You again!

Comment: i think that line 3 1 is incorrect. Check my answer

Comment: @RomanPekar  -Thank you sooo much for showing me the implementation. The line 3 1 is right. I should have give some background of the data. I actually wrote an algorithm that analyzes the closeness of texts of a group of file(could be in thousands sometimes). So, the possibility is that text1 closely matches text3 and vice-versa and hence the results above.

Comment: my implementation is not working on graphs, only on trees (number of trees). non-recurssive part of the CTE gets all records where parent is not a child of any of the records. You have to preprocess you data before and remove duplicates

Comment: @RomanPekar - Hmm..that makes sense. I am just flushing out all my analysis to a text file which is later bulk inserted to a sql table. So, i will pre-process my data as you suggest. Thank You Pekar!

Comment: Question re-phrased: I just need to group similar items together. i.e. Parent, children and children of children. Right now I have two columns called Parent and Child. I need a way to combine parent with all its children and grandchildren. I am assuming the question is now clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

well you can do it in SQL. Syntax a little bit depends on RDBMS, but generally it's something like (you'd better create some indexes on you child and parent columns or copy it to temporary table and then create indexes, otherwise it could be slooow)

```
;with CTE as (
    select Parent as ID, Child as Child, 1 as num
    from temp
    where Parent not in (select Child from temp)

    union all

    select C.ID, p.Child as Child, num + 1 as num
    from temp as p
        inner join CTE as C on C.Child = p.Parent
)
select
    C.ID,
    stuff(
        (
            select ', ' + cast(t.Child as nvarchar(max))
            from CTE as t
            where t.ID = C.ID
            order by t.num, t.Child
            for xml path(''), type
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
    , 1, 2, '')
from CTE as C
group by C.ID
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97061/5)

Comment: +1, Sweet Zombie Jesus...

Comment: thanks, it may be not the the best performance-wise, but it's one query :)

Comment: @RomanPekar It just occurred to me that I don't have to pre-process the data as discarding/ignoring the vice-versa(like 3 1 while 1 3 already exists) records wouldn't really affect the output. You are awesome! I have to try this on my table of 13,864,177 records !

Comment: be careful, I suggest to create indexes or copy data into temporary table. Let me know how my query will work.

Comment: @RomanPekar - Honestly I don't know much about SQL, creating indexes etc, but very eager to learn! I know only basic SQL and am good at C#. The query is running, will update you once done. Thanks so much again!

Comment: @RomanPekar - Well, i looked up online how to create an index and did so for the Parent column. Re-running your query now. Let's see how it goes. people like us are able to survive in jobs with the help of good people like you! Thanks !

Comment: you could also build index for child column

Comment: @RomanPekar - I tried the query but unfortunately it terminated as it exceeded 100 iterations. I don't know what to do. I used to do the process of grouping using C# logic but since there are several thousands of records, i encountered out of memory exceptions and hence thinking of an alternative now!

Comment: You could try to add maxrecursion option to you query http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx. I'll write in more when I'll be near my comp

Comment: changed query. But you have to remove cycles (like 1 3, 3 1) or you will end with infinite recursion